# PHP COM and CrystalReports

Tags: php, oracle, com, crystal-reports, export

I'm trying to export a CrystalReports report using PHP and save it to the server. I'm using PHP's COM class. I'm not able to get it to work, it just hangs on Export(true). My code is as follows:

```
$obj = new COM('CrystalReports13.ObjectFactory.1') or die('1');

    $get = $obj->CreateObject('CrystalDesignRunTime.Application') or die('2');
        $report = $get->OpenReport('C:\\xampp\htdocs\\crystal\\Packslip_RepSrv.rpt', 1) or die('3');
        try {
            $report->Database->ConvertDatabaseDriver('crdb_odbc.dll', false);
            $report->Database->Tables(1)->SetLogOnInfo('REMOVED', 'REMOVED', 'REMOVED','REMOVED');
            $report->EnableParameterPrompting = 0;
        $report->DiscardSavedData;
        $report->ParameterFields->Item(1)->AddCurrentValue('9455');
        $report->ExportOptions->DiskFileName='report.pdf';
        $report->ExportOptions->FormatType=31;
        $report->ExportOptions->DestinationType=1;
        $report->Export(false);
        $report = null;
        $get = null;
        $obj = null;
        print "<embed src=\"report.pdf\">";
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e);
        }
```

Does anything above look out of the usual? To my knowledge I'm doing everything properly, but it hangs on the ***$report->Export(false);*** part.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use CrystalDesignRunTime

Use CrystalRunTime